# Data table does not display data and stuck in the processing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, datatables

I am trying to show my JSON data in the table by using Data table. However, data table keep stuck in the processing like this and I don't know why.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvmertbp/

[image]

JSON format

[image]

console.log(data)

[image]

Java controller code

```
@GetMapping(value="/projects")
public @ResponseBody List<Project> getProjects() {
     return projectService.findAllProjects2();
}
```

I know this is the old question, but I have tried everything I can but it just don't work.

Comment: Could you add your code as text instead of images? Preferably using something like https://jsfiddle.net/. Makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: I just added JSFiddle in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server response is returning an array of result , not an object with `data` key array ,

So you data table will search in the result for a `data` array key , but not found , in your case you should specify the param `dataSrc` as empty , so it'll take it as ana array ,

Check here the [doc](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#tableProject').DataTable({
         processing: true,
         serverSide: true,
         ajax: {
             url: "/projects",
             type: "GET",
             contentType: "application/json",
             dataSrc: '', // <------------------------ here set empty string
             data: function () {
             },
             success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
             },
         },
         paging:true,
         columns: [
           {data: "projectNumber"},
           {data: "name"},
           {data: "status"},
           {data: "customerName"},
           {data: "startDate"},
         ]
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the success function, that seemed to work for me:

```
success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
},
```

You should also check that your array is in the "data" object, if it's just a flat array you should pass an empty string to dataSrc. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5snrvL4m

Comment: You should also check that your array is in the "data" object, if it's just a flat array you should pass an empty string to dataSrc. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5snrvL4m/